# i want to loop over some link using beautifulsoup which are in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

> I have 2 CSV file, in which I fetch required links into CSV and in other CSV I fetch the links which is required from the same website but different page. I am unable to loop over the link one by one, please suggest me some way so I can do it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request  
data = pd.read_csv("link.csv")
data2 = pd.read_csv("requiredlink.csv")
data2.columns = ["required"]

data.columns = ["aname", "links"]
alllinks = []
requiredlinks = []
alllinks = list(data.links)
print(alllinks)

for link in alllinks:
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
```

> above I had tried  but I stuck,
> 1 CSV file name is alllinks
> 2 CSV file name is requiredlink

Comment: print(alllinks) does this line prints all links in the csv?

Comment: yes for the first csv

Comment: then for link in alllinks: this line will loop through one by one.. what is the problem actually?

Comment: I have 2 CSV file, I file has 20 link and other has 30, I want to loop over one by means first it takes first link from 1 CSV and loop over all the link in second CSV and it takes second link and loop over all the link in the second CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need nested loop. 
lets, a variable allLinksOfFirstFile contains all links of first file and  allLinksOfSecondFile contains all links of second file.

```
for firstFilesLink in allLinksOfFirstFile:
    print(firstFilesLink)
    # this is the link of your first file
    for secondFilesLink in allLinksOfSecondFile:
        print(secondFilesLink)
        #here secondFilesLink is each link of second file for firstFilesLink
        #do other tasks
```

Comment: thanks for this, I am using beautiful soup so I want to open the link,  then how can i do , i am trying this ' url = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url,from_encoding="utf-8" 'html.parser')
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)

Comment: check this repo : https://github.com/Shayokh144/Scrape_and_Download_with_Python